# Get HANDLE from QFile

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I have a `QFile`, but I need to call some Win32 functions on it that accept only a `HANDLE`. Is there a way to retrieve the underlying `HANDLE` of the `QFile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way that uses `_get_osfhandle()` (available in MinGW and VS):

```
QFile file;
....
HANDLE handle = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(file.handle()).
```