# Get file size using GetFileSize reports a segv on a valid file

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, file-io, filesize

I have an application that scans file and collects meta data about a file. One function is to get the file size of a file. To do so, I am using the `winapi` function [GetFileSizeEx(Handle, PLARGE_INTEGER)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex). The parameters require a file `HANDLE` and a reference to a `PLARGE_INTEGER` aka (`*LARGE_INTEGER`).

To get a file `HANDLE` in Qt, it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707263/get-handle-from-qfile) to get the file handle using [QFile::handle()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#handle) and pass the result into [_get_osfhandle(int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle?view=vs-2019) and cast it as a HANDLE.

```
HANDLE handle = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(file.handle()).
```

Using this handle, pass it with a `PLARGE_INTEGER` variable into the [GetFileSizeEx(Handle, PLARGE_INTEGER)] which returns 0 if the operation failed or `!= 0` if the operation succeeded.

`GetFileSize(HANDLE, PLARGE_INTEGER)` returns with:

- 0 (or failure), one can use [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) in accordance with this list of [error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) (as a start, there are many more) to help.
- any non-zero value indicating success

**Problem:**

Using this approach, I attempt the same on a valid file, however I get a SEGV when calling `GetFileSizeEx(Handle, PLARGE_INTEGER)`. I attempted this before and after calling `QFile::open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)` as a test, however it fails non the less.

```
 int localHandle = file.handle(); // handle returns -1 as expected
 bool localOpen = file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
 if (localOpen) {
      int localFileHandle = file.handle(); // returns a valid >0 handle value
      HANDLE handle = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(localFileHandle); // returns a valid > 0 handle value
      PLARGE_INTEGER l = PLARGE_INTEGER(); // representation value of 0
      BOOL b = GetFileSizeEx(handle, l); // segv
      if (!b) {
           qDebug() << getLastErrorMsg();
           return QFileInfo(filepath).size();
      }

      return l->QuadPart;
 }
```

Did I do something wrong?

---

See attached screenshot

[image]

**MVCE**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "windows.h"
#include <comdef.h>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QFileInfo>

#include <windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <io.h>

static QString toString(HRESULT hr)
{
     _com_error err{hr};
     const TCHAR* lastError = err.ErrorMessage();
     return QStringLiteral("Error 0x%1: %2").arg((quint32)hr, 8, 16, QLatin1Char('0'))
            .arg(lastError);
}

static QString getLastErrorMsg()
{
     DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
     QString s = toString(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lastError));
     return s;
}

static qint64 getWinAPIFileSize(QString filepath)
{
     QFile file(filepath);
     if (!file.exists()) {
          return 0;
     }

     int localHandle = file.handle(); // handle returns -1 as expected
     bool localOpen = file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
     if (localOpen) {
          int localFileHandle = file.handle(); // returns a valid >0 handle value
          HANDLE handle = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(localFileHandle); // returns a valid > 0 handle value
          PLARGE_INTEGER l = PLARGE_INTEGER(); // representation value of 0
          BOOL b = GetFileSizeEx(handle, l); // segv
          if (!b) {
               qDebug() << getLastErrorMsg();
               return QFileInfo(filepath).size();
          }

          return l->QuadPart;
     }

     return QFileInfo(filepath).size();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

     QString src = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/.bash_history"); // change path to a valid file on your PC

     qint64 size = getWinAPIFileSize(src);
     qDebug() << size;

     return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a `PLARGE_INTEGER` is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type `PLARGE_INTEGER` is an alias for "pointer to `LARGE_INTEGER`". And `PLARGE_INTEGER()` is a default value initialization for the type "pointer to `LARGE_INTEGER`". And for all pointers such an initialization is a null pointer.

That means the definition

```
PLARGE_INTEGER l = PLARGE_INTEGER();
```

is equivalent to

```
LARGE_INTEGER* l = nullptr;
```

Which means you pass a null-pointer to `GetFileSizeEx`.

You need to create an actual `LARGE_INTEGER` object, and pass a pointer to that object using the address-of operator `&`:

```
LARGE_INTEGER l;
GetFileSizeEx(handle, &l);  // Pass pointer to the variable l
```

Comment: aha. See that was my logic for the `= PLARGE_INTEGER` part. My next question (related by doesn't suite an entire new question) is how do you know that. I posted the definition of `PLARGE_INTEGER` in the post, but it does not mention any constructor of the sort, atleast not what I see.

Comment: @CybeX Simple types (like for example a pointer to *any* type) can be [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Value initialization is also sometimes called "**zero** initialization" because for e.g `int` the default value is zero. For a pointer the default value is a null pointer (which could also be seen as zero in a sense, especially considering that the compiler can recognize `0` as a null pointer in the correct context).

Comment: @CybeX And knowledge of the different [initialization categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) comes with experience (and good references... ;))

Comment: @cyb And once you realize, that we have [some 20 ways to initialize an object](https://youtu.be/9-_TLTdLGtc?t=225) you are a fair bit closer to leaving the hell that is C++ behind. For good.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are mishandling the `PLARGE_INTEGER`.  You are creating a `PLARGE_INTEGER` (aka `LARGE_INTEGER*`) pointer that doesn't actually point anywhere, which is why `GetFileSizeEx()` crashes when it tries to write out the file size.

You need to allocate a `LARGE_INTEGER` (not a `PLARGE_INTEGER`) and then pass its memory address to `GetFileSizeEx()`, eg:

```cpp
static qint64 getWinAPIFileSize(QString filepath)
{
    QFile file(filepath);

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        int localFileHandle = file.handle();
        HANDLE handle = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(localFileHandle);
        LARGE_INTEGER l;
        if (GetFileSizeEx(handle, &l)) {
            return l.QuadPart;
        }
        qDebug() << getLastErrorMsg();
    }

    return QFileInfo(file).size();
}
```

That being said, there is really no point in using `GetFileSizeEx()` manually at all in this situation.  Depending on its implementation (which I can't check), `QFileInfo.size()` will either open the file for you, or it will simply query the file's size directly from the filesystem's metadata and not actually open the file at all:

```cpp
static qint64 getWinAPIFileSize(QString filepath)
{
    return QFileInfo(filepath).size();
}
```